# Different style for ordered list number and content

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have the number (or letter or numeral etc.) of an ordered list have a different style than the content without having some kind of div or span tags inside each list element?

Comment: what do you mean by different style than the content? Is the content a list too. Can you provide some code?

Comment: Do you mean like different font properties like family, color, size for the list item number/letter as opposed to the content of the list item?

Comment: @MarcAudet Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Garan: If I were doing this, I would consider using an inner wrapper around the list item content and apply a specific style to it.  Alternatively, I could also set up a custom counter for the list and place the counted in a pseudo-element and apply the style to the pseudo element.  The pseudo-element approach may be more practical is you have large lists and you are not too worried about really old browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with setting the list-style to 'none' and replacing the default numbering with CSS counters and pseudo-elements. Example: http://jsbin.com/agagoc/1/edit

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: my-awesome-counter;
}

li {
  counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
}

li:before {
  content: counter(my-awesome-counter);
  /* any style for numbers, as if they were spans before the content of LIs, goes here */
}
```

Comment: So essentially, as the page is being displayed, it dynamically increases the count and uses that counter?

Comment: The counter is incremented for any element for which the counter-increment property is set, starting from the value it was reset to with counter-reset (default is 0). Good article on CSS counters is here: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/automatic-numbering-with-css-counters/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Turns out the person I was doing the work for didn't mind the numbers being the same style.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can [like this:](http://jsbin.com/uheyub/1/edit)

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  counter-increment: myCounter;
}
li:before {
    content: counter(myCounter);
    font-size: 19px;
    color: red;
}
```